# R: removing obs. only if a value of a column is present for the same (duplicate) id

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently working in R with a data table containing two columns: id and type. The type value can be female, male, or both. There are instances where ID is repeated with differing values of Type. I'd like to delete obs. with Type==Both but only if obs. for the same ID are present that have a type == female and type==male.

This is my current table:

```
    id    type
    1     both
    1     female
    1     male
    2     both
    2     female
    3     both
    3     male
    3     female
    4     both
    5     male
    6     female
```

I'd like the table to resemble the following:

```
    id    type
    1     female
    1     male
    2     both
    2     female
    3     male
    3     female
    4     both
    5     male
    6     female
```

*obs with type==both are only deleted if the same id also contains type==female and type==male

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'id', `if` `all` the 'male', 'female' values are present `%in%` type, then return a logical expression where 'type' is not 'both' or `else` return TRUE in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter( if(all(c('male', 'female') %in% type))  type != 'both' else TRUE)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   id [6]
#     id type  
#  <int> <chr> 
#1     1 female
#2     1 male  
#3     2 both  
#4     2 female
#5     3 male  
#6     3 female
#7     4 both  
#8     5 male  
#9     6 female
```

---

Or create a logical expression using `unique` number of elements in the 'type' column

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%  
  filter(n_distinct(type) == 3 & type != 'both' | n_distinct(type) < 3 )
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[all(c('male', 'female') %in% type) & 
       type != 'both' |!all(c('male', 'female') %in% type) ], id]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L), type = c("both", "female", "male", "both", "female", "both", 
"male", "female", "both", "male", "female")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option in `base` R:

```
maleIDs <- df1[which(df1$type == "male"), "id"]
femaleIDs <- df1[which(df1$type == "female"), "id"]
bothIDs <- df1[which(df1$type == "both"), "id"]

df1[!(df1$id %in% bothIDs
    & df1$id %in% maleIDs
    & df1$id %in% femaleIDs 
    & df1$type == "both"),]
```